# How do I send email from nodemailer in nodejs using gmail?

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

I followed the documentation but google says the app is less secure than its security level. And there is no option to allow access to such apps anymore.

```
  const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');


let mailTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'xyz@gmail.com',
        pass: '*************'
    }
});

let mailDetails = {
    from: 'xyz@gmail.com',
    to: 'abc@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Test mail',
    text: 'Node.js testing mail for GeeksforGeeks'
};

mailTransporter.sendMail(mailDetails, function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('Error Occurs');
    } else {
        console.log('Email sent successfully');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

less secure apps is deprecated util 14/06/2022

you need to enable two step auth in your google account
https://myaccount.google.com/signinoptions/two-step-verification

and create App Password
https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords

so google will send a App password that you can login with nodemailer

Answer (score 4):

At the time of writing, Less Secure Apps is no longer supported by google. And you can't use your google account password.

You're gonna have to generate a new app password.

App passwords only work if 2-step verification is turned on. Follow this steps to get the app password

1. Go to https://myaccount.google.com/security
2. Enable 2FA
3. Create App Password for Email
4. Copy that password (16 characters) into the pass parameter in Nodemailer auth.

```
const client = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
        user: "username@gmail.com",
        pass: "Google-App-Password-Without-Spaces"
    }
});

client.sendMail(
    {
        from: "sender",
        to: "recipient",
        subject: "Sending it from Heroku",
        text: "Hey, I'm being sent from the cloud"
    }
)
```